# Namespace / Prefix of Controller in Default Module

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework-modules

In my zf application I have 3 modules:

- applicant
- company
- admin

And, in my application.ini I've picked a default module

```
resources.frontController.defaultModule = "applicant"
```

So, some of controllers classes are named like:

```
class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action /* in Applicant Module */
class Company_IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
class Admin_IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
```

Since applicant is my default module, I don't need to use module name as prefix in class name.

How can I use the prefixed way to name classes in my default module?

I want to use these class names

```
class Applicant_IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
class Company_IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
class Admin_IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Exception' with message 'Invalid controller specified (error)' in ZendFramework-1.11.6/library/Zend/Controller/Dispatcher/Standard.php on line 248
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you note, controller names in the default module do not require prefixing (Ex: `SomeController`), while controllers in non-default modules require prefixing (Ex: `Admin_SomeController`).

In module-based app, I personally find it more consistent to prefix *all* controllers with the module name. This was filed as [an issue](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-1808) and fixed in [apparently in version 1.5](http://framework.zend.com/changelog/1.5.0) by adding a front controller setting `prefixDefaultModule`.

So, in `application/configs/application.ini`, you could add:

`resources.frontController.prefixDefaultModule = true`

I use it all the time and think it's great. ;-)

Comment: D'oh! @Benjamin Cremer beat me to it. He should get the accept.

Comment: When I try this, I get the error: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Exception' with message 'No default controller directory registered with front controller' in M:\Zend_Framework\library\Zend\Application\Bootstrap\Bootstrap.php on line 91 - Any ideas?

Comment: Just realised, it's beacuse in your example it is 'frontcontroller' and should be 'frontController' with a capital 'C'...

Answer (score 2):

See the ZF Documentation: [The Dispatcher](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.controller.dispatcher.html)

> As of 1.5.0, you can now do so by
>   specifying the prefixDefaultModule as
>   TRUE in either the front controller or
>   your dispatcher:

You can set it in your application.ini ...

```
resources.frontController.prefixDefaultModule = true
```

.. or from anywhere else with:

```
Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->setParam('prefixDefaultModule', true);
```